# Avoid zombie data in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

Recently I faced an issue in a customer setup with a 3 node cluster, where one node went down and came online only after 12 days. The default gc_grace_seconds for most of the table has been set to 1 day in our scenario and there are a lot of tables.

When this down node came up, stale data from this node got replicated to the other nodes leading to zombie data in all the three nodes.

A solution that I could think of was to clean the node before making it join the cluster and then run a repair which could prevent the occurrence of zombie data.
Could there be any other possible solution to avoid this issue where I don't need to clean the node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never bring a node back online if it has been down for longer than the shortest `gc_grace_seconds`.

This is a challenge in environments where GC grace is set to a very low value. In these situations, the procedure is to completely rebuild the node as if it was never part of the cluster:

1. Completely wipe all contents of `data/`, `commitlog/` and `saved_caches/`.
2. Remove the node's IP from its seeds list if it is listed as a seed node.
3. [Replace the node with itself](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html) using the `replace_address` flag.

Cheers!